# Does the Pokémon Bank know I got the first evolutions of a non-alolan Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-bank

Ok, big question. I started Pokémon Sun without knowing there was no national Pokedex. Through wonder trade and GTS, I have acquired starters and other Pokémon from other regions. However, I evolved them, not thinking that would be a problem. If i purchase Pokémon bank, will the national dex feature know I did at one point have a pokemon's first evolution? Or do I need to breed them all to get them registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Pokémon Sun and Pokémon Bank together. If I remember correctly the National Dex will only register the transferred Pokémon. Thus you gonna need to breed them all and transfer them in order to get them registered.